# Fixed Window Size; Zurb Foundation

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm currently trying out Zurb Foundation and am having problem with my window size.

```
<body id="gradient">
        <div id="title" class="small-2 large-6 large-centered text-center  columns">Example</div>    
</body>
```

Currently I have the word `Example` set to `large-6` instead of `large-12` because if I go beyond more than `large-10` then my window size will have an increased width causing the left-right scroll to appear.

However, I thought I had set my css correctly to prevent that from happening.

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#gradient {    
    background: #00BFFF;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right bottom, #086A87, #00BFFF);
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #086A87, #00BFFF);
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
```

I thought setting my `background-size` to 100% 100% would have my window fixed and prevent any additional width and height (as in I don't want to scroll up/down/left/right).

Reason I want to fix this is when I drag my screen to reduce the size from full screen, the word `Example` will disappear from the center of the screen and stays more towards the right side of the window thus you can't see the word.

Sorry if this is confusing, let me know if you need any clarifications. Thanks!

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/5vdobycy/9/

Hopefully I did it right, as you can see `Example` is not entirely center as you can scroll to the right and part of the word falls in plain white background. jsfiddle doesn't show really show it the way it looks on my browser but pretty much that's the problem I am having.

However, not sure if I didn't include Foundation right or it's because of jsfiddle, but there's no differences in changing the columns i.e. `large-6` shows the same as `large-12` on jsfiddle.

Comment: What about making a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo?

Comment: please provide your code in jsfiddle..

Comment: What is your exact problem? Do you want the word to be exactly in the center or do you want it to be in the center of that block but limiting what? How do you want it to look when the screen is smaller  than the required width? Scale down the text size? Do what? If you tell us, we will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get text to center is to use full-width columns and to apply `text-align: center` on them:

```
<div id="title" class="small-12 text-center column">Example</div>
```

Your fiddle has multiple problems:

- you did not include Foundation at all
- you overrode the column placement with

  ```
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  left: 400px;
  ```
- `small-2` was too small to contain the text, so it poked out on the right:

  [image]

  That is also the reason why the text did not appear to be centered — the column itself was, but the text only escapes the centered column to the right.

Neither setting `width`, `height` or `background-size` do anything to prevent the page from scrolling. For that, you would need the [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) CSS property.

Here is a simple example that works:

```css
#gradient {
    height: 100%;
    background: #00BFFF;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right bottom, #086A87, #00BFFF);
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #086A87, #00BFFF);
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
#title {
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #FF8000;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.3.1/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div id="gradient">
    <div class="row ">
        <div id="title" class="small-12 text-center column">Example</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

**css**

```
#gradient {
    background: #00BFFF;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right bottom, #086A87, #00BFFF);
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #086A87, #00BFFF);
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
#title{
    padding-top:20%;
    font-size:40px;
}
```

**html**

```
 <body>
    <div id="gradient">
        <div id="title">  Example :)  </div>
    </div>
</body>
```